# On save app closes without returning to previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have three activities with flow `LoadingPage`->`ClassActivity`->`ClassActivityEdit`. The code of `LoadingPage` is

```
public class LoadingPage extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_page);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoadingPage.this, ClassActivity.class);
            mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            LoadingPage.this.finish();
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            //finish();

        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

}

Once the application opens the `ClassActivity` view when I perform a button click it moves to `ClassActivityEdit`. The code in class activity to start next activity is

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
    Intent addNewClass =
            new Intent(ClassActivity.this, ClassActivityEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(addNewClass,1); // start the Activity

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // call super's method
}
```

In `ClassActivityEdit` on save of activities I return to `ClassActivity` using the following code

```
View.OnClickListener saveClassActivity = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(className.getSelectedItem().toString()!="" && courseID.getSelectedItem().toString()!="" &&
                activityType.getSelectedItem().toString().compareToIgnoreCase("select") != 0 && activityName.getText().length() != 0 &&
                dueDate.getText().length() != 0 ){
            System.out.println(activityType.getSelectedItem().toString());
            AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask =
                    new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                            saveClassActivities(); // save classes to the database
                            return null;
                        } // end method doInBackground

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                            Toast.makeText(ClassActivityEdit.this, activityName.getText().toString() + " saved",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                            returnIntent.putExtra("result","fine");
                            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                            finish();
                            //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(ClassActivityEdit.this);
                        } // end method onPostExecute
                    }; // end AsyncTask

            // save the contact to the database using a separate thread
            saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null);

        }
        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ClassActivityEdit.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null);
            builder.show(); // display the Dialog
        }
    }
};
```

I catch the returnIntent in `ClassActivity` using

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    }
}
```

The data is saved and the control is coming back into RESULT_OK condition. But the app closes without any sort error instead of staying at `ClassActivity`. My manifest for the above activities is

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoadingPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ClassActivity"
        android:label="Class Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.teamtreehouse.oslist.ClassActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ClassActivityEdit"
        android:label="Class Activity Edit">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.teamtreehouse.oslist.ClassActivityEdit" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This happens if I dont save but press back button from `ClassActivityEdit` too

Comment: show your onActivityResult code please

Comment: @MustanserIqbal it is present in the question above

Comment: i need more code.. whats written in it.

Comment: @MustanserIqbal In the update view section even if put system.out.println it closes the app

Comment: i think finish(); is causing the problem. use this ClassActivityEdit.this.finish(); and then try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108887/discussion-between-human-and-mustanser-iqbal).

Comment: @human does logcat say anything? any errors?

Comment: @Pooya Skipped 222 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: do you see the Toast message you are making? "... saved" ?

Comment: @Pooya yes. I can see and it is saving in db.

Comment: how about removing: finish(); startActivity(getIntent()); from onActivityResult

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108890/discussion-between-human-and-pooya).

Comment: What is this code supposed to do in `onActivityResult()`: ` finish();
startActivity(getIntent());`?

Comment: @DavidWasser onactivityResult I want remain that activity without it being finished

Comment: Then why are you finishing the `Activity` and starting it again? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was extending an activity which was creating this problem. I am not sure why but removing reference to that activity and implementing those methods in my current activity solved my problem